# using JQuery to check if a radio button is selcted

Tags: jquery

I have radio button embedded within a table, I need to use JQuery without names or ids to selects each radio button in a row and check if it has been selected if not then  to colour it in.

Please any suggestions?

Comment: please share your html code also.

Comment: You'll need to provide your HTML markup for us to be able to help with that. We don't currently know the structure of your site.

Comment: i've a bit of it! I can access each button but its the if condition statment used to get at it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below jQuery, where using `.each()` you can iterate over each radio button inside row and check if it is selected or not.

CSS:

```
.changeColor{background-color:red};
```

jQuery :

```
$('#tableId tr input:radio').each(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
     $(this).addClass('changeColor'); 
});
```

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle link with your problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is wath your looking for:

```
$("table input[type=radio]:not(:checked)").css("background-color", "red");
```

or you can toggle it with a class.

**Edit :**

```
$("table input[type=radio]:not(:checked)").closest("td").css("background-color", "red");
```

to make the td red wich the radio button in.

Comment: This was what I was looking for! but when I used this I makes the entire row red! When  I specifically define the radio button colour doesn't change

Comment: modify my answer to make the td red. You get the idea, select what ever you need to be the color you need.